# IIS 7 and Ms Access 2007 32 bit on Windows7 (64 bit)

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

System Info:
Windows Professional. 64bit.
IIS 7.0
Ms Office 2007 32 bit (from task manager)
No Visual Studio.
Running classic ASP

Need to connect with MS Access 2007 database.

```
<%
    Dim objCon
    Dim objRec
    Dim objSql
    Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("db/dbTest.accdb")
    Set objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")     
    objSql = "select * from tblLogin;"  
    objRec.Open objSql, objCon
    Do While not objRec.EOF
        Response.Write ("<br>")
        Response.Write (objRec("uid")) 
        Loop    
    %>
```

Using above code in .asp file.

Error message: An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. 
Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

What I did:
Following above link information.
Enable 32 bit apps in IIS manager.
Enable 32 bit applications on 64 iis
cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
Using below option to select .accdb manually (is it correct way?)
%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Access 2003 or earlier the  database will have the extension .mdb, not .accdb

Use the JET OLEDB driver

```
PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.Mappath("db/dbTest.mdb")
```

JET is 32 bit so you do need to enable 32 bit applications

For Access 2007 onwards use the ACE driver as per your example.  ACE is 64 bit so you don't need to enable 32 bit applications, in fact you probably need to have them disabled - IIS seems to be either/or in these situations

Comment: Oh! But the database, is in MS Accesss 2007 fomrat (.accdb). So what will be provider then?

Comment: I assumed you were talking about a database created in an old version of Access. see here http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-HA010341552.aspx. If it does have the accdb extension then ACE is the driver to use.  ACE is actually a 64 bit driver so you should DISABLE 32 bit applications.  Also, in case you don't know, the JET driver ships with Win 7 Pro but you need to install ACE

Comment: Alternatively, you could save a copy of your database in the old mdb format

Comment: It worked with .mdb database. Thanks for information.